# Prove of complex numbers inequality $|a\bar{b}| \leq |a|^2 + |b|^2$

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, absolute-value

Is it true that for any two complex numbers, say $a, b$, the following inequality holds:
$|a\bar{b}| \leq |a|^2 + |b|^2$ ? How can we prove this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have

$$|\overline b|=|b|$$
and from 
$$(|a|-|b|)^2\ge0$$
we get
$$|ab|\le \frac12(|a|^2+|b|^2)$$

Comment: This is, of course, stronger than the original statement. (Hence the statement in the question should be a strict inequality.)

Comment: No it isn't strict! Think about $a=b=0$.

Comment: Woops. Yes, that case must be excluded for it to be strict.

Comment: Very nicely argued, @Sami!